# Google Chart custom tooltip not displayed as HTML

Tags: javascript, charts

Why isn't the tooltip for the red line rendered as HTML? I have added the option `tooltip: { isHtml: true }` but that does not help.

https://jsfiddle.net/w7hymkua/2/

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart', 'line']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

function drawBasic() {
  var query = new google.visualization.Query("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T8eNrLpk7bOuvHGDojsHALzoxHHHoQ6iJ7AZIAnZntE/edit?usp=sharing");
  query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
  var data = response.getDataTable();
  data.setColumnProperty(3, 'role', 'tooltip');
  data.setColumnProperty(3,'html','true');
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  var options = {
    title: 'Weight mot Date',
    legend: 'none',
    bar: {
      groupWidth: '95%'
    },
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Date',
      format: 'yyy-MM-dd',
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Weight',
      viewWindow: {
        max: 100,
        min: 0,
      },
      ticks: [0, 25, 50, 75, 100],
      focusTarget: 'category',
      tooltip: { isHtml: true }
    }
  };
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Comment: Most likely because the query is not returning `<strong>Test</strong>`, but has replaced the < and > with HTML entities at that point already ...?

Comment: Okay. So how do I fix that?

Comment: If neither the query mechanism itself or the `getDataTable` method have any options to specify how to handle this, then you'll probably have to replace them in `data` yourself.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but you're supposed to be able to render HTML in the tooltips.

Comment: _"but you're supposed to be able to render HTML in the tooltips"_ - and you would be, if your actual input data was indeed `<strong>Test</strong>`. But my suspicion is that it simply isn't, but that you actually got `&lt;strong&gt;Test&lt;/strong&gt;` already.

Comment: Okay. My input data is a cell in a spreadsheet that has "<strong>Test</strong>" in it. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T8eNrLpk7bOuvHGDojsHALzoxHHHoQ6iJ7AZIAnZntE/edit#gid=0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237116/discussion-between-rawland-hustle-and-cbroe).

Comment: That might well be, but that does not necessarily mean that the query mechanism or getDataTable actually treat it correctly.